# Cuda: Architecture of GTX460 and code-related seperation of grid/block/thread

Tags: architecture, cuda

Hey there,
so far what I understood is the following: The GTX460 1GB (GF104) has 2GPCs with 4 SMs each, so 8SMs in total of which 1 is disabled, which means: 7SM ("Streaming Multiprocessors"). Each SM has 48 Cuda Cores (**Is that what we call a Thread? And can it be understood like ONE core of a CPU like the Q9550-Quadcore?**), so in total 336 Cuda Cores.

So what I don't understand right now: Why this 'complicated' architecture and not only like on a CPU to say: 'Okay, the GPU has N cores, thats it!'?

Assuming I have a certain program which is seperated into a grid of B blocks and each block of T threads (so B*T threads in total), can I somehow tell that ONE block is always connected to ONE SM or NOT? Because if it would be like that, this would make things harder for the coder since he should know how many SMs there are to optimize the parallelization to each graphics-card. E.g.: When I would have a graphics card with 8 SM and my program would only seperate the data into a grid of 1 block with N threads, I could only use one SM which would not use all its ressources!

Is there any way to only use some of the threads of the card when coding my program? I would really love to benchmark the speedup by running my program on 1..M Threads in total, where M is the total number of cuda cores (if this is equivalent to 'thread'), but how to do this? Is it sufficient to code my program like that:

```
cudaKernel<<<1, 1>>>(...)
```

to

```
cudaKernel<<<1, M>>>(...)
```

and run it each time? The only problem which I see here is the following: Let's assume I have the simple vector addition example:

```
#define SIZE 10
__global__ void vecAdd(float* A, float* B, float* C)
{
   int i = threadIdx.x;
   A[i]=0; 
   B[i]=i;
   C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
}
int main()
{
    int N=SIZE;
    float A[SIZE], B[SIZE], C[SIZE];
    // Kernel invocation

    float *devPtrA;
    float *devPtrB;
    float *devPtrC;
    [...]
    vecAdd<<<1, N>>>(devPtrA, devPtrB, devPtrC);
}
```

when I would now set `vecAdd<<<1, N>>>` to `vecAdd<<<1, 1>>>` the single thread wouldn't calculate C to a N-size vector because the only thread would just calculate the first value of A, B and thus C. How to overcome this problem than?
Thanks a lot for clarifying in advance!! You will help me a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, the answer to most of what you're asking about is no. Not just not, but heck no.

The general idea with most GPU programming is that it should be implicitly scalable -- i.e., your code automatically uses as many cores as it's given. In particular, when it's being used for graphics processing, the core get split between executing the three types of shaders (vertex, geometry, fragment/pixel). As such, the number of available cores can (and often will) vary dynamically, depending on the overall load.

There are a few reasons the GPU is organized this way instead of like a typical multicore CPU. First, it's intended primarily for use on "embarrassingly parallel" problems -- obviously enough, its primary purpose is applying similar code to each of a large number of pixels. Although you're not using it exactly the same when for CUDA code, that's still the basis of the hardware design. Second, as alluded to above, the cores are actually split between at least three different purposes, and can be split between more (e.g., a graphics application using some cores, and your CUDA code using others). Third, the extra abstraction helps keep your code immune to changes in the hardware. It lets you specify just the computation you need, and it deals with scheduling that on the hardware as efficiently as it can.

Comment: thanks so far. Am I right assuming that a thread is the same as a cuda core (which is the same as one of the 4 cores of a quadcore CPU)?

Further: Is it than possible at all to limit number of threads in my program and how to do it in my example?

Comment: @bjoern: No. A thread is not the same as a core. A thread is a smallest virtualized unit of parallel work there is in CUDA. As a programmer you have explicit control over the number of threads which are run, but not how those threads relate to the physical hardware.

Comment: OKay and how do I know than the max. number of threads onj a GTX460 when there are 336 Cuda cores? Has each core a fixed number of threads?

Comment: The maximum number of threads on a GTX460 is 1024 * 65535 * 65535 * 65535 = 288217182213504000. There is no such thing as a per core thread limit in CUDA, all aspects of the hardware are abstracted away in the programming model. You can have 65535^3 blocks, each block can have up to 1024 threads. Blocks are distributed across the multiprocessors in the GPU, which run the threads within those blocks in a fashion similar to an SIMD unit on a modern x86 processor. The number of cores and how that relates to the execution is irrelevent to the programming model.

Comment: Hm that sounds a bit confusing to me so far... Is there any way to "limit" the threadnumber so that I can only use 5%, 10%, 15%...100% of my GPUs ressources for benchmarking the programs speedup? Thanks!

Comment: Not meaningfully, no. The GPU relies on having a lot of parallel work to give good performance by hiding the latencies which are all the way through the the architecture. You would be much better off benchmarking a fully optimized code at different size problems instead.